# Azure rest API images missing when listing images

Tags: ruby, rest, azure, missing-data

So when I list the images using the Ruby SDK, I get all of the publicly available ones, but the ones that I have created myself are not included. They do show up in the web console though... I've even tried using the REST API and constructed a Net:HTTP object as illustrated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499770.aspx). I get a 5xx error after setting the content-length (even though it isn't listed as a required header) to anything, including 0... I have had success using the same code on other azure RESTful urls, so I am unsure as to why this specific one is giving me an error....

Does anyone have any clue as to why my images aren't listed? Any experience with the endpoint linked above? Just fyi, heres my ruby request code:

```
# HTTP request code
def get(uri)
  uri = URI.parse(uri)
  pem = File.read('/path/to/management_cert')
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(pem)
  http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem)
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  request['x-ms-version'] = '2014-06-01'
  request['Content-Length'] = 0

  http.request(request)
end
```

Here is the calling code:

```
# The invoking line
get 'https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/vmimages'
```

???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer (kinda).... I guess the servers were having an issue that day as I re-ran the code and got the data I needed... The above code (now fixed) works!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must go through the API first. Here is link of rest API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499770.aspx

1. You are making <strike>POST</strike> request instead of GET. The Method should be 'GET'
   **request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)**
2. You have to set Content-Length

Comment: Whoops, i added the wrong code... (All the same, but it does a GET instead of a POST) I already read that doc (I never ask questions until i've read the docs), and I did do a GET. I get a 5xx error.... I wouldn't get a 5xx if i did a POST.... why do i get a 5xx? How do I compute Content-Length? There is no body...

Comment: You can try to set **http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE**. And please do post exact error message.5xx could be                     500 - Internal Server Error,                                              501 - Not Implemented,                                               502 - Bad Gateway,                                                 503 - Service Unavailable,                                         504 - Gateway Timeout,                                               505 - HTTP Version Not Supported

Comment: See above... i answered my own question